# Extract Date from excel and append it in a list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an column in excel which has dates in the format ''17-12-2015 19:35". How can I extract the first 2 digits as integers and append it to a list? In this case I need to extract 17 and append it to a list. Can it be done using pandas also?

Code thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
Location = r'F:\Analytics Materials\files\paymenttransactions.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location)
time = df['Creation Date'].tolist()
print (time)
```

Comment: Please provide code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: import pandas as pd

Location = r'F:\Analytics Materials\files\paymenttransactions.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location)                                                                          time = df['Creation Date'].tolist()
print (time)

I have been able to take the column and convert that into the list.
A small portion of the list is  as below.

['11/12/2015 18:59', '22/12/2015 07:42', '17/12/2015 22:44', '28/12/2015 22:50', '17/12/2015 19:35', '5/12/2015 18:46', '8/12/2015 20:28', '8/12/2015 0:36', '27/12/2015 17:57', '10/12/2015 12:19', '10/12/2015 12:16'

Comment: You can always edit your question. It'd be a lot nicer if you could add that example to the actual question instead. Code in comments is quite unreadable as you can see.

Comment: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience.I have pasted the code in the questions now.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the day of each timestamp like

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

location = r'F:\Analytics Materials\files\paymenttransactions.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(location)

timestamps = df['Creation Date'].tolist()
dates = [datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') for timestamp in timestamps]
days = [date.strftime('%d') for date in dates]

print(days)
```

The `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'`and `'%d'` bits are format specififers, that describe how your timestamp is formatted. See e.g. [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for a complete list of directives.

`datetime.strptime` parses a string into a `datetime`object using such a specifier. `dates`will thus hold a list of `datetime` instances instead of strings.

`datetime.strftime` does the opposite: It turns a `datetime` object into string, again using a format specifier. `%d` simply instructs `strftime` to only output the day of a date.